# How to push into an existing session array , key and value in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

With php I used

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['cart']) || !isset($_SESSION['cart'][$product])) {
    $_SESSION['cart'][$product] = 0;
    $_SESSION['cart'][$product] = $_SESSION['cart'][$product] + $product_quantity;
            
}else{
    $_SESSION['cart'][$product] = $_SESSION['cart'][$product] + $product_quantity;
}
```

I tried with put() but it's not working, cause every time I try to insert a new value it replace the first one

```
session()->put('cart',[request('variant_id') => request('quantity')]);
```

With push() I put inside the array cart another array with key and value

```
session()->push('cart',[request('variant_id') => request('quantity')]);
```

Is there a way to insert into session array with key and value cause right now I can't figure it out how to do it

Comment: Hi @Alexandru you can first pull data from session and store it into variable, then you can work/update this variable after completing work you can put is back to the session. like `$cart = $request->session()->get('cart');    $cart['quantity'] =  $cart['quantity'] +$request('quantity');  $request->session()->put('cart', $cart);`

Comment: It's not working, it delete all the records every time I try to add another one

Comment: try initializing with empty array first `session()->put('cart', [])` then push the values.